# Как задать рабочую папку при создании SCHTESKS через CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, schedule

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно через командную строку создать задание в планировщике задач с указанием рабочей папки?

Само задание создаю так `SCHTASKS /Create /ru "SYSTEM" /SC DAILY /TN AllVision /TR "\"%appdata%\AllVision\start.VBS"" /ST 10:25:00`

Задание создается, но что бы мой скрипт работал, нужно в самом задании указать рабочую папку. Делать это руками каждый раз нет возможности, нужно при создании задания через CMD каким-то образом передать адрес рабочей папки `"%appdata%\AllVision\"`

Заранее благодарен!

[image: Рабочая папка].

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю сам себе и другим, кто в будущем столкнется с этим.
Что бы задать рабочую папку во время создания задачи через CMD нужно передать ключ `/v1`. Почему именно его, я сам не до конца понял, если кто сможет объяснить, буду благодарен!

В итоге у меня получилось `SCHTASKS /Create /ru "SYSTEM" /v1 /SC DAILY /TN AllVision /TR "\"%appdata%\AllVision\start.VBS"" /ST 10:25:00` и все заработало

Comment: Сделайте свой ответ принятым в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

У SCHTASKS есть такой ключ комстроки, как `/XML XMLfile`, который выполняет импорт параметров задачи из XML-файла. В котором вполне можно указать и каталог запуска. и любые другие параметры. Сам XML можно создавать в процессе выполнения, если команда выполняется из пакетного файла, или подготовить заранее.